# Passing selected value of Dropdown into API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, user-interface

Hi I need to populate list in `dropdown` when the page gets loaded so I put the same in `componentDidMount()`.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const countryData = res.data;
      this.setState({ countryData });
    });
  }
```

This data needs to be part of dropdownlist.

```
      <select id="dropdown">
        {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
          <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
            {countryData}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

list is getting displayed like below.

[image]

Myrequirement is if user select any value in `dropdown list` that `value` should be passed in `API` as parameter to `backend`.

what changes I need to do in `Select` or `Option`. I know how to write call API in `reactjs` using `axios`.that I will manage.
My updated code is below.

```
<select id="dropdown" onChange={this.downLoadFile(e)}>
                {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
                  <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
                    {countryData}
                  </option>
                ))}
</select>



downLoadFile(e) {
    this.setState({ selectValue: e.target.value });
    alert(selectValue);
  }


this.state = {
      countryData: [],
      selectValue: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.downLoadFile = this.downLoadFile.bind(this);
  }
```

Its not working. what wrong I am doing?

Edit1:-

```
 downLoadFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ selectValue: e.target.value });
    alert(selectValue);
  }

   <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.downLoadFile}>
                {this.state.countryData.map((countryData) => (
                  <option key={countryData} value={countryData}>
                    {countryData}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
```

it is giving below error.
[image]

in `constrtor` I have below code.

```
this.state = {
      selectValue: ''
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch API after the update of the selected state.

```
downLoadFile(e) {
    this.setState({ selectValue: e.target.value }, () => {
      fetchSomeApi(this.state.selectValue).then((res) => {
         updateSomewhere(res);
      }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });
    alert(this.state.selectValue); // < --- changes this line
}
```

`this.setState` has second parameter as callback. So you could use that for after state update event.

Also, you can update the function call.

```
onChange={this.downloadFile)
```

Comment: thank you Siva. it is giving some error. I have edited in code.

Comment: @Mahima I have updated the answer. you should use `this.state.selectValue` for getting selected value

Answer (score 1):

You should pass function to onChange event.
Like:

```
<select id="dropdown" onChange={(e) => {this.downLoadFile(e)}}>
```

or

```
<select id="dropdown" onChange={this.downLoadFile}>
```

The way you do is just pass the return value of this.downLoadFile

---

Update:

```js
alert(selectValue)
```

must be

```js
alert(this.state.selectValue);
```

Comment: Can you check my code of method. I have updated the question and -put that part as well.

Comment: @Mahima we also update his answer after your edit :)

Comment: hey, I did not understood.